# A list of all Laravel env variables?

Tags: php, laravel-5, configuration, environment-variables

Anyone knows a way to have a list of all possible env variables in current Laravel installation? Or maybe a web source with a comprehensive list? Is there any? I searched a lot but found nothing (apart those already wrintten in .env..)

Comment: You can have a look at this
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/accessing-custom-environment-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php artisan tinker --execute='print_r($_ENV);'

Answer (score 0):

Guess there are dozens of ways.

```
git clone https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git
cd laravel
grep -orh env\(.*
```